Create a device font size setting dependent widget that resizes within ranges
I'm trying to create a widget that has two texts in a row, each one inside a container so to give them different background colors. The text and their containers should increase when a larger font on the device is set.
I tried using a ConstrainedBox on the Row itself passing a minHeight of 30 and a maxHeight of 60 but the containers always take the maxHeight even when using small fonts on the device accessibility settings.
.
I then tried to use the ConstrainedBox directly on the individual containers instead of on the Row, but without setting the height for the containers the behavior is the same, they take the maxHeight from the ConstrainedBox resulting as the picture above.
If I set an height of 1 for each container then they'll take them minHeight resulting in covered up text when using large fonts in device accessibility settings.

As I understood it ConstrainedBox forces additional constraints to its child assigning the minHeight if its child's height is smaller, or the maxHeight if its child's height is bigger. That's why I tried with the containers height at 1 so to be forced to be as the minHeight, but it only works for the small font device settings.
Is the device font size setting not affecting the fontSize of the Text widget or they are independent so Flutter still reads the same font size no matter what the device's font setting are? This could explain these behaviors I'm seeing.
If I don't set any constraint at all then the containers do vary proportionally t the text when choosing different device font setting but can become too small.
What I'm trying to achieve is that the size the containers vary proportionally depending on the device font setting but within a certain range.


Can you spot what I'm doing wrong?
class TextSizeDependentHeader extends StatelessWidget {
  const TextSizeDependentHeader({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return
        // ConstrainedBox(
        //   constraints: const BoxConstraints(minHeight: 30, maxHeight: 60),
        //   child:
        Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: const BoxConstraints(minHeight: 30, maxHeight: 60),
            child: Container(
              // height: 1,
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              // constraints: const BoxConstraints(minHeight: 30, maxHeight: 60),
              color: Colors.black,
              child: const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0),
                child: Text(
                  'Text 1',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: const BoxConstraints(minHeight: 30, maxHeight: 60),
            child: Container(
              // height: 1,
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              // constraints: const BoxConstraints(minHeight: 30, maxHeight: 60),
              color: myYapLiteGreen,
              child: const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0),
                child: Text(
                  'Text 2',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
      // ),
    );
  }
}

